# react-router: change route based on scroll position of body

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a layout with a fixed sidebar on the left, and the content on the right.

The content is divided by sections, the sections are listed in the sidebar.

```
----------------------------
| #sidebar | #content      |
|          |               |
| - a      | - a           |
| - b      | ...           |
| - c      | ...           |
|          | - b           |
|          | ...           |
|          | ...           |
|          | - c           |
|          | ...           |
|          | ...           |
----------------------------
```

The sidebar, being fixed, scrolls with the page.

My current router is:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path='/:category' component={App}>
    <Route path='/:category/:section' component={Content} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

I'd like to make the `:section` segment change when the page is scrolled to the header of the section inside `#content`.

My attempt was:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  let scrollTop = this.props.scrollTop

  let activeItem = this.refs[0]
  let found = _.values(this.refs).find(function(element) {
    return findDOMNode(element).offsetTop >= scrollTop
  })
  browserHistory.replace('/' + this.props.category + '/' + found.props.slug)
}
```

But doing so I get into a loop...

How can I achieve the result?